# In the Summary Report CSV outfile not getting the Avg,Min,Max,Std.Deviation Responsetimes

Tags: jmeter

When I looked at the Summary report csv output file, I don't see Min, Max,Avg,Std.Deviation response times there.

Is there any way to get Min, Max,Avg,Std.Deviation response times into the csv output file?

Please advise me!

Thanks,
Raj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are statistical values so they are being calculated. You have 3 options to get them:

1. Using Excel (or equivalent) functions get the values out of sampler data (you are interested in `elapsed` column using the following functions:

   - [MIN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MIN-function-61635d12-920f-4ce2-a70f-96f202dcc152)
   - [MAX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MAX-function-e0012414-9ac8-4b34-9a47-73e662c08098)
   - [AVERAGE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGE-function-047bac88-d466-426c-a32b-8f33eb960cf6)
   - [STDEVP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/STDEVP-function-1f7c1c88-1bec-4422-8242-e9f7dc8bb195)
2. You can use the result file to build the [HTML Reporting Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) which has Statistics table as well as several charts

   [image: JMeter Statistics Reporting Dashboard]
3. Use a 3rd-party analysis solution like [BM.Sense](https://sense.blazemeter.com/) with enhanced configurable version of [Aggregate Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) and [interactive charts](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/understanding-your-reports-part-4-how-read-your-load-testing-reports-blazemeter).

Comment: Hi Dmitri,Yes I am able to get using JMeterCMD.bat  able to get all the values displayed in the UI of Aggregate Report  which is equal to options 1 & 2  you have mentioned.But I will try option#3 too. Thanks a lot!-Raj

Answer (score 0):

But that is not supposed to be written, that is supposed to be **calculated** basing on **sampler results** that are **actually** get written there in this file.

And the calculations are elementary, you may do it yourself, or load that file back into JMeter at any time and get them.